# How to migrate from Runkit to Ubuntu server?

Tags: json, node.js, http, endpoint, runkit

I have a working javascript with an endpoint on Runkit. It responses to HTTP JSON requests. However, when I move this script to Ubuntu server - it doesn't respond to the requests. I guess it should be adopted for working on the external server. Is there any guidance online? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Need to create an HTTP(s) server by yourself or use some frameworks, specifically designed for this purpose (e.x. Express, Koa, Hapi, etc.).

To make it listen all the time in background the one can use **pm2** or **forever**, for example.

Comment: This is not an answer to your own question. If you want to expand on the scope of your question, edit the question and don't post the extra content as an answer. Read the SO guidelines before posting.